# Sin and cos in PHP difference from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, trigonometry

I am trying to get sin and cos of an angle that is `9.590124942537262`.

In Javascript I would do it like that:

```
var a = Math.sin(9.590124942537262);
var b = Math.cos(9.590124942537262);
```

The results would be:

```
a == -0.16459459028073223
b == -0.9863613034027227
```

If I do the same operation in PHP like this:

```
$a = sin(9.590124942537262 * M_PI / 180); // ≈ 0.16737916966136 rad
$b = cos(9.590124942537262 * M_PI / 180);
```

I get these results:

```
$a == 0.16659953926461
$b == 0.9860246414349
```

Question is: how do I make these operations uniform, so that PHP returns correct value with a minus sign? I tried rounding my angle but that didn't help.

Comment: Why aren't you converting to radians in the JavaScript version?

Comment: @Pointy, I can't change JS code, I am converting it to PHP.

Comment: Is your input (`9.59...`) in degrees? If so, the aswers should be positive for both sin and cos.

Comment: That's the difference between the sin/cos of `9.590124942537262 degrees` vs `9.590124942537262 radians`. Or in general: `angle !== angle * Math.PI/180`

Comment: Well the trig functions in JavaScript also work in radians; your PHP code is clearly different from the JavaScript code and it's not clear why. What if you just pass the values to `sin` and `cos` in PHP just like the JavaScript code?

Comment: Well, why are you doing so in the PHP version?

Comment: Damn it, they both use radians. Sorry, I should've not converted my angle (which is in radians already) to radians again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Both PHP and JavaScript's trigonometry functions work in radians

In your PHP example, you are trying to convert from degrees to radians, because you're actually supplying radians to be converted into radians, you're just adding Pi radians, or 180 degrees, hence why you get the negative result.

You should be able to do the code in each language with the same parameter:

```
Math.sin(9.590124942537262);
Math.cos(9.590124942537262);

sin(9.590124942537262);
cos(9.590124942537262);
```